# Combine pandas dataframes with interval data (Top-Bottom) and create new df with smallest possible intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with depth interval data and attributes

`df1`

```
ID Top Bottom Value_1  
A     0   2       CC  
A     2   8       DD  
A     10  15      EE  
B     3   20      FF  

df2   

ID Top Bottom Value_2  
A     0   4       XX  
A     4   6       YY  
A     8   20      ZZ  
B     0   10      NN  
B     10  50      MM
```

I want to combine these using pandas into a new dataframe that has the smallest intervals possible per ID, and make a column with the combined value (based on the smallest interval). Like below

`df_combine`

```
ID Top Bottom Value_1 Value_2 Value_combined  
A     0   2       CC    XX        CC  
A     2   4       DD    XX        XX  
A     4   6       DD    YY        YY  
A     6   8       DD    -         DD   
A     8   10      -     ZZ        ZZ  
A     10  15      EE    ZZ        EE  
A     15  20      -     ZZ        ZZ  
B     0   3       -     NN        NN  
B     3   10      FF    NN        NN  
B     10  20      FF    MM        FF  
B     20  50      -     MM        MM
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following steps:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**1/ Explode each dataframe (each row repeated as many times as Bottom - Top)**

```
def explode_df(df, value):
    df['interval'] = df['Bottom'] - df['Top'] + 1
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.Bottom - df.Top, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
    df['Top'] = df['Top'] + df.groupby(['ID','Top','Bottom']).cumcount()
    return df[['ID', 'Top', value, 'interval']]

df1_expl = explode_df(df1, 'Value_1')
df2_expl = explode_df(df2, 'Value_2')

df1_expl.head(10)

[Out]:
ID  Top Value_1 interval
0   A   0   CC  3
1   A   1   CC  3
2   A   2   DD  7
3   A   3   DD  7
4   A   4   DD  7
5   A   5   DD  7
6   A   6   DD  7
7   A   7   DD  7
8   A   10  EE  6
9   A   11  EE  6
```

**2/ Merge df1_expl and df2_expl on ID and Top**

```
dfcomb_expl = pd.merge(df1_expl, df2_expl, on=['ID','Top'], how='outer')\
    .fillna(0).sort_values(['ID','Top']).reset_index(drop=True)

dfcomb_expl.head(10)

[Out]:
ID  Top Value_1 interval_x  Value_2 interval_y
0   A   0.0 CC  3   XX  5
1   A   1.0 CC  3   XX  5
2   A   2.0 DD  7   XX  5
3   A   3.0 DD  7   XX  5
4   A   4.0 DD  7   YY  3
5   A   5.0 DD  7   YY  3
6   A   6.0 DD  7   0   0
7   A   7.0 DD  7   0   0
8   A   8.0 0   0   ZZ  13
9   A   9.0 0   0   ZZ  13
```

**3/ Aggregate**

a) Create column keep equal to 1 for each row to keep

```
    dfcomb_expl['keep'] = ((dfcomb_expl['ID'] != dfcomb_expl['ID'].shift()) \
 | (dfcomb_expl['Value_1'] != dfcomb_expl['Value_1'].shift()) \
 | (dfcomb_expl['Value_2'] != dfcomb_expl['Value_2'].shift()))\
.astype(int)
```

b) Filter out on rows to keep

```
dfcomb = dfcomb_expl[dfcomb_expl['keep']==1].reset_index()
```

c)  Calculate *Bottom* and *Value_combined* based on intervals calculated at step 1

```
dfcomb['Bottom'] = dfcomb['Top'] + dfcomb_expl.groupby(dfcomb_expl['keep'].cumsum())['ID'].transform('count')

dfcomb['Value_combined'] = np.where(dfcomb['interval_x'] == 0, dfcomb['Value_2'], \
                          np.where(dfcomb['interval_y'] == 0, dfcomb['Value_1'], \
                          np.where(dfcomb['interval_x'] < dfcomb['interval_y'], dfcomb['Value_1'], dfcomb['Value_2'])))

df_combine = dfcomb[['ID','Top','Bottom','Value_1','Value_2','Value_combined']]

df_combine

[Out]:
ID  Top Bottom  Value_1 Value_2 Value_combined
0   A   0.0 2.0 CC  XX  CC
1   A   2.0 4.0 DD  XX  XX
2   A   4.0 6.0 DD  YY  YY
3   A   6.0 8.0 DD  0   DD
4   A   8.0 10.0    0   ZZ  ZZ
5   A   10.0    12.0    EE  ZZ  EE
6   A   15.0    17.0    0   ZZ  ZZ
7   B   0.0 2.0 0   NN  NN
8   B   3.0 5.0 FF  NN  NN
9   B   10.0    12.0    FF  MM  FF
10  B   20.0    25.0    0   MM  MM
```

**4/ Remarks**
This solution does not take into account special cases where Bottom > Top, and where for a specific ID (in df1 or df2) we have 2 rows including the same range.

Comment: Hi Anne, Thanks for your solution. In reality my df and interval depths a range from 0-100meters and intervals can be in centimeters. I end up with a value error:     df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.BOTTOM_DEPTH - df.TOP_DEPTH, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
ValueError: count < 0